# How can i manage AVAudioplayer in all views of my app

Tags: ios, ipad, avfoundation, avaudioplayer, viewcontroller

I'm using AVAudioplayer to play a background song in my App. The problem is that I want to have a button so I can stop/play the song whenever i want in each of the views of my app.

Is there an easy way of doing this? or do I Have to declare the player in each of the views...?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here I can think in two ways to do this..

First:

Create a view **controller** that stands over all other views.. Take a look on view container if you don't know how to do this.. You can make this top view (view controller.. not a view) the player screen.. with the play button, next button and etc.. So the avplayer would be declared on this viewController.

The second idea has a point that goes against some texts that describe we should not create and consume variables and methods on AppDelegate even though it works fine.. to do this create the AVPlayer and the methods to play and stop the music on the App delegate, then import the appDelegate.h on your class and execute the methods like this:

```
[((AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]) playSongWithName:@""];
```

I hope it helps..